# Is there a way to put drawable in every text view created dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, textview

```
  val textView = TextView(this)
    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    params.setMargins(100, 70, 0, 0)
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18f)
    for (element in arr) {
        textView.append(element + '\n')
    }
    textView.layoutParams = params
    linear?.addView(textView)
```

> i've tried to add textView.setbackgrounddrawablewithintrisicbounds in the loop but only shows one

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
```

Try this in xml file:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
       />
```

Also, check the official documentation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Comment: but i create it dinamically i dont have any text view in the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
for (int i = 0; i <2 ; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("testing");
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        Drawable img = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_humidity_icon);
        img.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
        tv.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
        rootLinearLayout.addView(tv);
    }
```

You can customize it according to your need. Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: this worked but the drawable does not appear aligned with the textview

Comment: you can change the adjust the drawable height or width

Comment: how do i do that? i changed the drawable in the resources but did not work and then changed the setbounds and did not work either

Comment: no need to change the drawable. you can adjust width and height by    img.setBounds(0, 0, 20, 20).  
You can give value according to your requirement

Comment: i did exactly that but the drawable and the text are still not aligned

Comment: Did you try any of the values like 10, 30 etc.?  It might work.
Also can explain the alignment issue . I mean whether you want in center or any thing else.

Comment: the drawable is like on the corner bottom of the first letter like this _word and i want to be like this -word

Comment: you can try to add gravity on textview. If that could help